# Discord Python: Get a users top role's name and color

Tags: python, discord

Is there any way I can do this? I haven't found any answer that answers this.

```py
@bot.command()
async def check_rank(ctx)
    if "Administrator" in ctx.author.roles
        color = ctx.author.color
    await ctx.send("Checked rank!")
```

Something similar? I have this modmail code and I want it to use the users role color and name in the embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the top roles from `member.roles` and the color from `member.color`

```py
@bot.commmand()
async def check_rank(ctx):
    author = ctx.author # we get the member object
    top_role = author.roles[-1] # first element in roles is `@everyone` and last is top role
    color = author.color
```

### References:

- [roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Member.roles)
- [color](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20color)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the Roles of a discord.Guild object with .roles. (A discord guild is a discord server.) https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Guild.roles

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Member.colour

```
@client.command()
async def roles_colors(ctx):
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        await ctx.send(role.name)
```